# Display Category from WP Custom Post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Wrote this code to display specific category from custom post type on wp page.

```
    <?php

            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ?get_query_var('paged') : ((get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1);
            $blog_items_num = ($data['blog_item_number']) ? $data['blog_item_number'] : 3;
            $blog_order = ($data['blog_order']) ? $data['blog_order']  : "date"; 


            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'aeolus_news',
                'cat'=>'24',
                'posts_per_page'=>$blog_items_num,
                'orderby'=>$blog_order,
                'paged' => $paged
            );

            query_posts($args); 
            rewind_posts();
            get_template_part( 'content-news', 'single' );
            wp_reset_query();

            ?>
```

But nothing displays.

If comment out 'cat' => '24' then all posts/categories from the custom post type display.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, consider using [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of `query_posts` for post queries like this (see [this WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for details why)

Second of all, if you're using the category **id**, it's expecting an **integer** not a **string**, and the apostrophes around the id are making it a string.

Replace `'cat' => '24',` with `'cat' => 24,` (with no quotation marks around the 24). Right now it's looking for a category literally named "24".

Comment: Tried with WP_Query() and Changed to 'cat' => 24, with the same result.

Comment: Since it works with that line removed, either your category is a different ID than 24, or it's not actually a category and instead is a taxonomy where you'd use [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) instead